# Linq-to-sql timeout issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, linq, linq-to-sql

I am a student and newbie at linq queries and .net generally, so Im sure the code is very badly constructed.

I keep getting timeout errors for a set of linq queries like the example below. I am using it to generate a Report. Could anyone offer suggestions about how to optimise this query? Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
public IList<CountryOrderReport> CountryGetListEndRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var countryOrders = (from order in db.Orders

                         where order.FinancialStatus != "draft" && order.CreatedAt >= startDate && order.CreatedAt <= endDate

                         group order by order.Customer.BillingAddress.Country into users
                         select new CountryOrderReport
                         {

                             CountryName = users.Key,
                             TotalOrders = users.Select(g => g.OrderId).Distinct().Count(),

                             TotalSpent = users.Select(g => g.TotalDue).Distinct().Sum(),
                             AverageOrderValue = users.Select(g => g.TotalDue).Distinct().Sum() / users.Select(g => g.OrderId).Distinct().Count()

                         }).OrderByDescending(g => g.TotalSpent).Take(5).ToList();

    return countryOrders;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `Distinct`ing `TotalDue` is correct? What if there were two orders for $5? It seems it should simply be `Sum()`

Comment: As for optimization advice - you're calculating `TotalOrders` and `TotalSpent` twice (since we use them in the average). Create a select which grabs `CountryName, TotalOrders, TotalSpent`, and from that *select again*, and calculate the average based on the pre-calculated values.

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated. Both good points:)

Comment: Make sure you have indices on all the relevant columns - especially those used in the `where` clause.